# I have a land cover vector dataset, and would like to calculate the area of each land cover in ARC, how can this be achieved?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area

My land cover vector 25m data includes land cover types such as 'Broadleaved woodland' and 'urban'. I have cropped the dataset down to my study area and would like to calculate the area of each land cover in my study area (this information is not included in the attribute table). How can I calculate the area for each land cover?

Comment: You have land cover polygons, correct?

Comment: May be a duplicate.  See the answers here.  Solutions for both vector and raster are provided. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169657/area-calculation-of-mapped-categories-in-arcgis-10-1-basic/169717#169717

Comment: yes vector format so land cover polygons I believe

Answer (score 1):

If these are vector polygons you would open the attribute table, create a new field called area, then right click on the AREA header to the table, and select the calculate geometry option, select area and the unit of measurement you prefer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a new field in the attribute table.  Give it a name like "area" with a float data type.

Right click the new field and select calculate geometry and specify the units you want to display.

Once this is done you can select the land cover type you to analyze using the select by attributes tool.  Once the desired features are selected, right click the area field you just created and select "Statistics".  The sum will be the total area for the specified land cover type.

Comment: For the last part you could just right click the "area" field in the attribute table and use the summarise command. This will be easier than having to select each land cover type and do statistics on them one at a time.